# Append var to div

Tags: javascript

I made a Roulette game, but now I´m struggeling to use an int in the Append method. I want to use the var number as the paragraph of the appended div. Thanks in advance!

```
if (Red == true) {

  Red = false;
  var randnum = Math.floor((Math.random() * 4) + 1);
  var number;
  switch (randnum) {
    case 1:
      number = 1;
      break;
    case 2:
      number = 3;
      break;
    case 3:
      number = 5;
      break;
    case 4:
      number = 7;
      break;

  }


$("#WheelList").append("<li><div class='red'><center>'number'</center></div></li>");
```

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5922647/how-do-i-combine-2-javascript-variables-into-a-string first search stackoverflow then ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this.In javascript `+` operator is used for concatenation.

```
if (Red == true) {

  Red = false;
  var randnum = Math.floor((Math.random() * 4) + 1);
  var number;
  switch (randnum) {
    case 1:
      number = 1;
      break;
    case 2:
      number = 3;
      break;
    case 3:
      number = 5;
      break;
    case 4:
      number = 7;
      break;

  }


$("#WheelList").append("<li><div class='red'><center>"+number+"</center></div></li>");
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply concatenate the number with string using [`+` symbol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#String_operators).

```
$("#WheelList").append("<li><div class='red'><center>" + number + "</center></div></li>"); 
//                                          ---------^^^^^----^^^^^^----
```

Answer (score 1):

It's easy as this:

```
$("#WheelList").append("<li><div class='red'><center>" + number + "</center></div></li>");
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer!