# Double Variables in Javascript

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript Variable Variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592862/javascript-variable-variables)

There's a really handy thing in PHP (that I'm sure is sinful), but I'm looking for the JavaScript alternative.

In PHP I can do this:

```
$bar = 'var';
$$bar= 'test';

echo $var;
```

I am looking for something similiar in JavaScript.
I want to pass a name to a function and initialize a new variable with that name.
So:

```
function(name) {
    var name = new Function();
}
```

**Update:**
Ok, here's what I'm trying to do. I know there's an easier way..

I want to use multiple instances of something (let's say plupload for now).

```
var uploader = new plupload();
```

I am loading these dynamically and there will be multiples on a page.
The issue I'm having is that they all have to have a unique name, because I have to be able to call uploader.init(), uploader.refresh(), etc and have each one function independently.

As I said, I'm sure there's a better way.. I'm just not privy to it.

Comment: Can you explain why this is necessary?

Comment: `$var$bar = $foo;` isn't valid PHP.  You *can* do `${"var$bar"} = $foo;`, though.

Comment: you can achieve this using `eval()`, but it won't be easy to write all your code in eval :)

Comment: You can do that in PHP? :O If so it should've been on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1995113/419956).

Comment: If you know what you want is a hack, why are you going to do it, just makes you look foolish

Comment: So you have a pattern that you know to be evil, and you want to apply it to other languages. I don't know if it can be done in JavaScript but I sure hope it cannot.

Comment: AWOOGA AWOOGA, RED ALERT! I'm changing the bulb to RED. Step back and tell us what you're trying to achieve. There is a better way. Right now you think you want to do this, but soon you will know better. AWOOGA!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is sinful. In both PHP and JavaScript (and pretty much every other language) if you have a collection of related things, then you should represent them with an array (if they are ordered and not sparse) or an object/associative array (if they have names).

```
var bar = 1;
var foo = "test";
var group = {};
group[bar] = foo;
console.log(group[1]);
```

Variable variables are, essentially, fake arrays/objects. Use real ones instead — they give you much more power and are much easier to maintain.

Comment: I got this to work. Ends up I was doing something totally wrong when binding to the upload button, so everything was working the first time I did it (before I tried my sinful ways), but I was just throwing everything at the first "file list".

Answer (score 1):

Seeing your edit, I suggest you use an object to store your unique `plupload` instances.

```
var all_uploads = {};
all_uploads["unique_name_1"] = new plupload();
all_uploads["unique_name_2"] = new plupload();
all_uploads["unique_name_3"] = new plupload();
```

You can generate the "unique_name" strings in whatever way you want.

Another alternative is to use a simple array and `push()` each `plupload` instance on it.  Unfortunately, you'll have to search the array every time you want to find a particular instance, but if the array will stay small the performance trade-off is pretty minimal.

Comment: Ok, so this was my original approach, and the second one would never initialize. The buttons on the additional uploaders only functioned for the first one.

Comment: @gamerzfuse Without seeing more code (HTML and the Javascript that goes with it), it's hard to for us to diagnose and help your code's problems.