# Concatenation in variable names

Tags: javascript, variables, concatenation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript Variable Variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592862/javascript-variable-variables)
>   [Javascript dynamic variable name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117127/javascript-dynamic-variable-name)

Given several variables

```
var myVar0;
var myVar1;
var myVar2;
var myVar3;
var myVar4;

var randomNumber // generating random number between 0,4
```

As you see, all `myVar` variables are ended some number, also I have randomNumber (between 0 and 4).

What I need: if generating randomNumber equal 3, I want set `myVar3 = true`, if generating randomNumber equal 0,  set `myVar0 = true` and so on...

That is how make some like this

```
var randomNumber = 3;
myVar{randomNumber} = true;
//result:  myVar3 is true
```

Comment: Sounds like you might want to use an array instead.

Comment: I think it might not be possible ,as when you declare a variable (myVar0),java script takes it as a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use separate variables; use an array.

```
var myVar = [];

var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)
myVar[randomNumber] = true
```

Answer (score 3):

Use an [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array):

```
var myVar = new Array ():
myVar.push (false);
myVar.push (false);
...
var randomNumber = ...
myVar[randomNumber] = true;
```