# Variable name within a loop

Tags: javascript, syntax

I suspect I am making a mistake in a basic JavaScript syntax.

```
var my_array = new Array(10);

for (var count=0; count<my_array.length; count++) {
var my_array+count = "This is a variable number "+count+".";
document.write(my_array+count);
}
```

I want the loop to create series of variables that should be called **my_array0, my_array1, my_array2**, and so on. The code above is how I tried to do that, but it doesn't work. What's the correct way of naming the variable inside the loop?

**EDIT:** I know I could use my_array[count], but that's not what I'm looking for. What I need is to be able to name a variable inside the loop, using the index as part of the name of the variable.

Comment: You need to do `my_array[count]` instead of `var my_array+count`

Comment: Why do you want a series of variables with those names? What are you trying to accomplish here? If you want ten arrays, create ten arrays and put them in another array. Do you know what an array is? It is a thing that holds a list of multiple other things.

Comment: No, @Ed, what I want is series of variables that all have different names. I will be using array[count] for a different purpose within a loop, so I need to separate the variables from the array.

Comment: What are you trying to DO? WHY do you want a series of variables with different names? If you want ten things, put them in an array. If you want to put something else in a different array, create a second array.

Comment: I want to do something like this: var my_array0 = new Image(); my_array0.src = my_array[0];

Comment: But in more general terms, @Ed, I want to be able to dynamically name a variable inside a loop, using the value of the count as part of variable name. Is that possible at all?

Comment: An image isn't an array. Why are you putting an image in a variable named "my_array0"? You want two arrays: var imagesrc = new Array(10); var images = new Array(10); Populate imagesrc[0] through imagesrc[9] with the urls, then populate images with the Images, then assign the .src properties.

Comment: Probably a good way to do that, @Ed, but my question remains: how do I use the count variable as part of the name of a different variable inside a loop?

Comment: Don't do that. That's what arrays are for. They are much easier to use. It's cool to try to think of your own new ways to solve problems, but this one isn't a great idea. It's hard enough to learn programming without trying to do things the language doesn't want you to do.

Comment: @Figaro check my answer mate, but Ed has a point.

Comment: anybody cares to explain why my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16839033/variable-name-within-a-loop/16839168#16839168 is downvoted????

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript "Variable Variables": how to assign variable based on another variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/592862/javascript-variable-variables-how-to-assign-variable-based-on-another-variabl) and [lots of others](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+javascript+variable+variables&oq=site%3Astackoverflow.com+javascript+variable+variables&aqs=chrome.0.57j58j61.5718j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Comment: I experimented with various possible solutions, and your suggestion of using two arrays, @Ed, is the best one. I had to accept the answer that most directly addresses my original question, but you made me rethink the way I approached the problem, and I very much appreciate it. Your suggestion was the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This pattern is questionable, and the array seems unnecessary; however, here is one way to do it:

```
var my_array = new Array(10);

for (var count = 0; count < my_array.length; count++) {
  window['my_array' + count] = "This is a variable number " + count + ".";
  document.write(window['my_array' + count]);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to set the elements of an array, use the `[]` syntax:

```
var my_array = new Array(10);

for (var count=0; count<my_array.length; count++) {
  my_array[count] = "This is a variable number "+count+".";
  document.write( my_array[count] );
}
```

Furthermore, when specifying just an element of an array and not the array itself, drop the `var` in front of it!

Comment: That would be the obvious solution, but that's not what I want, for a number of reasons. I actually want to include the number in the name of the variablem rather than use my_array[count].

Comment: @Figaro If you want to create variables with "dynamic names" you need some pointer to the scope, where you want to add them. If this is the global scope, e.g., you could replace `my_array` with `window` inside the `for` loop, to create global variables of the respective name.

Comment: Sounds like a step in the right direction, @Sirko. That's exactly what I want to do, the variables with "dynamic names", but I think I want them local in scope – how can I do that?

Comment: @Figaro a starting point might be the answers in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2051678/1169798), but I know of no equivalent of the `window` object for a function scope. You could maybe bind your variables to `this`.

Comment: Tried window[count], @Sirko, it does what I want it to do, but it slows down loading of the page considerably. How would you bind variables to `this` - `this[count]`, or in some other fashion?

Comment: @Figaro Like mentioned many times in the comments, this is no good approach in general. Just use an object or array and put all your variables in there. But yes, `this[count`] should work, but maybe has some side effects, you don't want (see object orientation in JS for what `this[x]` is usually used).

Answer (score 2):

What's the correct way of naming the variable inside the loop? You don't.

If you just want a variable to hold that particular value, just use an ordinary variable. If you want lots of different values, stick it inside an array or object. But that's redundant here since you already have an array, so I'm really not sure what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

And if none of the previous answers suits you, you can always use `eval()`

```
var varName = 'my_array'
for (var count=0; count<my_array.length; count++) {
  eval(varName+count +" = This is a variable number "+count+".");
}
```

Edit: @Noah Freitas provides a better answer, without using `eval()`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an array.

```
var myarray = new Array();
myarray[0] = "1";
myarray[1] = "2";
myarray[2] = "3";
```

Answer (score 0):

You're redefining my_array inside the loop, and not accessing the variable correctly either. Try:

```
var my_array = new Array(10);

for (var count=0; count<my_array.length; count++) {
    my_array[count] = "This is a variable number "+count+".";
    console.log(my_array[count]);
}
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JK8Dv/)

Answer (score 0):

You can't **execute** on the left-hand side of the assignment operator (`=`), you can only **assign**. **Execution**, in javascript, takes place on the right hand side.

```
var my_array = new Array(10);
var var_hashmap = {}; // create a new object to hold our variables.

for (var count = 0; count < my_array.length; count++) {
    var key = "my_array" + count;
    var value = "This is a variable number " + count + ".";
    var_hashmap[key] = value;
    document.write(var_hashmap[key]);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var my_array = new Array(10);

for (var count=0; count<my_array.length; count++)
{
    eval("var my_array" + count + " = 'This is a variable number'+count+' and the variable name is my_array'+count");

}

alert(my_array0);
alert(my_array1);
alert(my_array2);
alert(my_array3);
alert(my_array4);
alert(my_array5);
alert(my_array6);
alert(my_array7);
alert(my_array8);
alert(my_array9);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pe97W/4/

Comment: downvote? for what? OP says "EDIT: I know I could use my_array[count], but that's not what I'm looking for. What I need is to be able to name a variable inside the loop, using the index as part of the name of the variable." also says "but my question remains: how do I use the count variable as part of the name of a different variable inside a loop?"  --i answered his question, first. And that's downvoting?