# Javascript: Naming arrays programmatically

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is it possible to create a new Array, giving it the name of the content of a variable?

For example something like this:

```
var nameofarray = "array_name";
var ¿nameofarray? = new Array();
```

So that `¿nameofarray?` gets the value of "array_name"?

Comment: This is a big code smell. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117127/javascript-dynamic-variable-name

Comment: `this[nameofarray] = new Array(); `

Comment: `this` will always refer to the object that a function is a method of, whatever that is, unless a different scope is set with `apply()`, `call()` etc. It doesn't really matter what `this` is, as long as we know it's available in the current scope and it's an object, we can use it, but yes, it could cause some strange behaviour if we don't keep close track of what `this` really is, or try accessing it in lower scopes, like we would with variables declared in higher scopes etc.

Comment: I'm not sure why I want to do that. I'm having problems with an asynchronous call, so that the second call overrides the Array before the first call writes the output. So I want to have two arrays, and I thought giving different names to the arrays would be a good idea. Excuse me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you are in global scope (called `window`) so:

```
var nameofarray = "array_name";
window[nameofarray] = new Array();
```

Otherwise it's only posible on objects:

```
function a() {
    var nameofarray = "array_name";
    var obj = {};
    obj[nameofarray] = new Array(); 
}
```

---

You can also use eval. Which is used for evaluating a string to JavaScript code:

```
eval('var '+ nameofarray+'=new Array()');
```

This will work in local scopes as well, but I hardly ever recorment it to anyone.

You would maybe like to read: http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/04/19/how-evil-is-eval/

Comment: For the love of polar bears, why would you assume global scope? The use of globals should be minimized. The assumption is therefore that the variables are local.

Comment: I'm guessing they wouldn't, but that's the only way to do it.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas Because OP doesn't specify any more details, but that said I would agree with you.

Comment: @NULL In my book, bad practices shouldn't be assumed.

Comment: @ginescapote You are welcome, remember that you can accept answer, can see on your profile that you haven't accepted any yet.

Comment: Thanks @NULL I hope accepting answers is clicking on the up arrow, I've done it now.

Comment: @ginescapote You have to click the tick below the arrows :) http://roi.webfactional.com/img/so/so_tick.png

Answer (score 1):

In PHP and other languages, they are called variable variables. This might help: [Javascript "Variable Variables": how to assign variable based on another variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592862/javascript-variable-variables-how-to-assign-variable-based-on-another-variabl)

Answer (score 1):

If `nameofarray` is declared in the global scope, you can use the `window` object:

```
window[nameofarray] = [];  // Use an array literal instead also
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

But you really shouldn't be doing this.